# Proof Rules to prove statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $I(x)$, $x < y$ and $x \leq y$ be predicates on naturals, where we know that $(x \leq y) \leftrightarrow [(x < y) \lor (x = y)]$.  Given the two premises $$\forall x : \forall y: [I(x) \land \neg I(y)] \rightarrow (x < y) $$ and $$\exists z : \neg I(z) $$ use the proof rules to prove the statement $$\forall x : \exists y : (x \leq y) \land \neg I(y). $$

> This is a question from my homework. I am not looking for the answers, I just would like to know what steps to take to start solving this. From what I understand, I use generalization, then instantiation. But after that I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: You have to start with the second premise and apply $\exists$-elimination. I think that you need "a trick" : the *valid* formula : $\forall x \forall z (x=z \lor \lnot (x=z))$ and use it in a proof by cases. The case with $x=z$ is strightforward; the case $x \ne z$ needs the first premise.